# ggplot2 apply alpha parameter to continuous fill scale legend to match map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to produce a map which is overlaid onto a road map. In order to make the road map visible, I am applying an alpha parameter that is not an aesthetic. When doing this, the continuous fill scale legend does not have the same alpha level applied. What I would like is apply the same alpha to the legend as what is done in the map. How can this be fixed?

```
library(tigris)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

options(tigris_class = "sf")

texas <- counties(48)

texas$fill <- rnorm(254, 50, 20)

ggplot(texas) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = fill, alpha = .5), color = "light grey") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

This solution applies the alpha, but it removes the gradient of the legend.

```
ggplot(texas) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = fill, alpha = .5), color = "light grey") +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.5)), alpha = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up finding a round about way to achieve what I was looking for by manually setting the fill scale using the `RColorBrewer` package to get the color information for the palette I am using and `scale_fill_gradientn`

```
 ggplot(texas) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = fill, alpha = .5), color = "light grey") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = alpha(c(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")), alpha = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: adding a `rev` will reverse the colors to match the original. `scale_fill_gradientn(colors = alpha(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")), alpha = .5))`

Answer (score 0):

`guides` can be used to modify the legend. Also adding `alpha = FALSE` will remove the alpha legend from the plot.

```
p + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 0.5)))
```

Comment: Hi ! and welcome to SO ;) Maybe you can provide a little bit of description about what your answer means ;)

Comment: This only partially works. It does apply the alpha, but you lose the gradient for the legend. See edited question.